# MATLAB histogram of image data (imhist) - Displaying data from one channel

Tags: matlab, matrix, histogram

This piece of code appears in a presentation that was given in a class I'm taking:

```
A = imread('office_2.jpg');   
imhist(A(:,1)),title('R band')
```

It is clear from the title of the histogram that the idea is to present the values of the red band. Yet to my understanding, achieving this would require the following line of code instead of the second one above:

```
imhist(A(:,:,1)),title('R band')
```

I think the original code only displays the values of the first column of the first band. Am I right?

Comment: That might be a typo in the slides? Your guess seems right to me. Unless `R band` might just mean a column?

Comment: Thanks Divakar but this is not a typo, it is repeated about 20 times in different slides. R band is the red channel, there also exist a blue and green one, all three of them are matrices.

Comment: @Nir, then I reckon you should ask your teacher about it, since in general RGB matrices will be of size `[m n 3]`, thus what your second line of code says.